# requiring non-core ruby gems for apache cgi scripts

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems

I'm having a hard time setting up Ruby CGI using Apache and RVM. I can execute scripts that require core gems just fine, but I can't require non-core gems and apache generates an error. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print 'hello there'
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'
require 'nokogiri'

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print 'hello there'
```

---

both scripts will run just fine from terminal, but apache throws up on the second one, giving this error:

[Tue Mar 25 20:53:13 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: main_index.rb
/home/aaachilless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)from /home/aaachilless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'from /home/aaachilless/Dropbox/aaachilless-me/cgi/main_index.rb:4:in `'

It looks like this guy [How do I get a Ruby CGI program that requires a gem to run properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775392/how-do-i-get-a-ruby-cgi-program-that-requires-a-gem-to-run-properly)
was having the same problem, but requiring rubygems doesn't solve it for me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: jimworm's answer didn't really help. apache can execute some scripts, so RVM must be loaded, right? I don't even have a system ruby installed.

Comment: I'm going to try running CGI using suexec and if that doesn't work I'm going to try uninstalling RVM, installing a system ruby, and running CGI on using the system ruby and if that doesn't work I'm going to try installing RVM as a system install and if that doesn't work I'm going to give up all hopes and dreams of ever becoming a web developer.

Comment: update: switching rubies using rvm affects my scripts when they are running from terminal, but not when they are being executed by apache. apache is running as me.

Comment: i really don't want to do a system-wide install of rvm but i guess i will try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this same problem by executing the ruby wrapper from RVM for the version I was using on the CLI in the shebang instead of just /usr/bin/ruby

`#!/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

rvm is applied per-user, so your (system? deploy? root?) user will need to load rvm when it starts up, probably using `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`.

Check out "Multi-user installs" in [the rvm docs](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting) for guidance.

Comment: My user as in the user that Apache runs as? I don't understand how this could be the problem. If Apache isn't loading RVM then I wouldn't be able to run any CGI scripts at all. But I'm only unable to run CGI scripts that require non-core gems.

Comment: If Apache isn't loading rvm, then it would still be able to use the system ruby if there is one, and it seems like it does because your scripts run.

Comment: I don't have a system ruby installed. That being said, if I execute a script the prints Apache's path using `printenv`, the PATH that's printed doesn't contain anything related to ruby or rvm.

Comment: This answer is the most likely from the information you have given. If you have tried running `rvm.sh` as indicated and it doesn't work, please post results such as error messages. Other potential answers are: 1. rvm is loaded but no rubies/gems are installed for apache user; 2. rvm is loaded but running wrong ruby; 3. rvm is loaded with right ruby but wrong gemset. Assumptions like "rvm must be loaded, right?" could ruin your life.

Comment: update: I am able to get everything executing correctly when the shebang line in my cgi script points to a system-installed ruby. Any time that the shebang line point to a RVM-installed ruby, the script will execute only when no non-core gems are required. Does that confirm that the RVM environment is not being loaded? Apache is running as the same user that I installed RVM under.

Comment: Oh I see. Does this link help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/182418/how-to-get-usr-bin-env-ruby-to-point-to-the-correct-ruby-environment

Comment: the solution offered on that link says to use /home/user/.rvm/bin/ruby as the shebang line, but my .rvm/bin doesn't contain a 'ruby' file. Also, my .profile file only contained the first of the two recommended RVM-loading scripts. I added the second, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: also, I noticed that switching rubies using RVM will change the LOAD_PATH of my scripts when executing from terminal, but not when Apache executes them. The LOAD_PATH when Apache is running the script is always for the system ruby. How could this be when Apache is running as myself?

Comment: Hmm stumped here myself, falling back on to the googles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010699/how-to-load-the-rvm-part-of-users-bashrc-to-run-ruby-cgi-scripts-under-apache

Comment: If all else fails there's always rbenv I guess?